# background image visible in cone shape css

Tags: html, css, html5-canvas

How to show a background image in the cone shape such that the part outside the cone is not visible. Example instead of red color i get the cone shape cropped image.

```
.cone{
    width:0;
    height:0;
    background-image:url('images/bg.png');
    border-left: 155px solid transparent;
    border-right: 155px solid transparent;
    border-top: 280px solid transparent;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top:-4%;
    left:24%;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);
    z-index:10;
}
```

Using the above code, It gives a complete circle and seems to be working just for solid colors. I want 8 cones with different background joined to form a circle. Any other way to achieve it for background images ?

[image: cone shape background]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can restrict drawing inside a path using `context.clip`**

A Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/fsux6pnz/

[image]

Example code:

```
// save the unclipped context state
ctx.save();

// begin defining a path
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(x1,y1);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x2,y2,x3,y3);
ctx.lineTo(cx,cy);
ctx.closePath();

// clip all drawing into that path
ctx.clip();

// draw the image on the canvas
// It will only display inside the defined path
ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);

// restore the context state
ctx.restore();
```

Comment: A great lead but how to show different images in different cones ?

Comment: You're welcome.  If you want different images in different cones then just change `img` for each `ctx.drawImage` Good luck with your project!